# Reminder notifications in the background - Android

Tags: android, android-service, android-workmanager

I am trying to create reminder notifications but in background service but I have a lot of problems with that. Let's start with basics.
I want to start background service with MainAcitivity and after restart device.
I've added to onCreate in MainAcivitiy:

```
Intent StartBackgroundService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StartBackgroundService.class);
sendBroadcast(StartBackgroundService);
```

So I am using **StartBackgroundService extends BroadcastReceiver** as something what's starts background process and there in **onReceive** I was starting background service.

At first I've created **BackgroundWorker extends Service** and there in **onStartCommand** I've wanted to manage my background process.

It worked good but it's look like since Android Oreo, **BroadcastReceiver** cannot start background service even if you add to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

<application
    //....... code

    <receiver android:name=".StartBackgroundService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

So, I've checked what can I do for background services and I could Foreground service or WorkManager but It looks like I should use WorkManager so I've tried.

So, again: in MainAcitity onCreate I am sending to BroadcastReceiver message to start background service:

```
Intent StartBackgroundService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StartBackgroundService.class);
sendBroadcast(StartBackgroundService);
```

**StartBackgroundService** look like this:

```
public class StartBackgroundService extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if(!BackgroundWorker.isServiceStarted) {
            BackgroundWorker.isServiceStarted = true;
            WorkRequest backgroundWorker =
                    new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(BackgroundWorker.class)
                            .build();
            WorkManager
                    .getInstance(context)
                    .enqueue(backgroundWorker);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally **BackgroundWorker**:

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends Worker {

    static boolean isServiceStarted = false; //flag to prevent running background process twice
    Context context;

    public BackgroundWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        backgroundProcess();
        return Result.success();
    }


    public void backgroundProcess(){
        //Code for background process:
        //Load from database time
        //Check time changed since last change
        //if not -> skip to sleep
        //if true -> clear all set notifications alarms
        //send notification at specific time from db
        //....
        //if notoifction was sent, change flag for getting time from db to another
        //and then sleep and open function again as below
        SystemClock.sleep(10000);
        backgroundProcess();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopped() {
        BackgroundWorker.isServiceStarted = false;
        Intent backgroundWorker = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StartBackgroundService.class);
        context.sendBroadcast(backgroundWorker);
        super.onStopped();
    }
}
```

So, changing from **Service** to **Worker** help with starting process in the background after restarting device. Yeah, it works but I have another problem. When I open application, background process starts but when I click "Overview" button and remove my application from last used apps, background process stops. It looks like it starts after 10-12 seconds but when I open application again, the background process starts again so there are two threads working in the background (so the flag BackgroundWorker.isServiceStarted is ignored). I didn't have such problem while using **Service** but then I couldn't open background process after restart devices so opening application was needed.

Should I maybe use foreground service for this? (I hate this because of this whole time active notification and not sure if I should use this for my problem due to e.g. battery usage). Is there any other way to achive my needs? I want to achive something similar to e.g. Google Calendar. You don't need to open application after restart, or you can remove it from Last used applications and it still sends you notifications when you should get remainer due to calendar event.